# Image not covering the whole "div" area

Tags: html, css

I've been looking online for a viable solution to my problem but could not find a clear answer, so I am posting it here.

The problem is that I want to have the image cover the entire , but there seems to be some left over space below the image and I can't seem to be able to fill it up. I'm taking about the blue space in the as shown in this image:

[image: img]

I'm not looking for a workaround the solution. I just want a definitive solution that corrects the problem

Comment: The thing is, there are a number of good definitive solutions, depending on the context and use of the image div. What's the reason you set an absolute pixel size for the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `display: block` or `vertical-align: top` to your img tag.

```css
img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.cover {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
 <img src="//unsplash.it/460/345" width="460" height="345" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
img {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
display:block
}
```

It is good if you can post a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). so then we can looking into your actual code.

Comment: He doesn't want the image to take up the whole document, just the .cover div.

Comment: Oh. I see. I was thinking about the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do for images is first determine if the image is landscape or portrait (i.e. if the image is wider than it is tall or vice-versa). Then I set the image's height or width to 100% depending on the orientation. And then overflow: hidden on the parent container so that the result is an image that has preserved the aspect ratio and covers the container.